# How can I predict the cardinality increase of an aggregation table, by grouping by another column?

Tags: sql, cardinality

Let's say I have visitor logs for my website. It contains many fields, such country, state, city, device, time, referral source, etc.

I have a stats table that groups by some of these dimensions, and sums the impressions, by hour. My site is extremely popular, so this table is large (billions of rows / day).

I have a new request: a data scientist now wants me group by ANOTHER dimension column here. Let's say we only did the granularity of country before, and now she requests to add a column to group by, which is STATE.

**How can I predict the cardinality increase of my stats table?**

It's tempting to say, it would be (cardinality of new dimension column we're grouping by) * # of existing rows. But this might falter because population density isn't evenly spread out: over a tenth of the US population lives in California, for example.

Comment: Hi - if you want to know what the specific granularity of a combination of values is then you’d need to actually run that specific query. If you just want generic/average granularity then do a distinct count on the columns and multiply these together. However, I’m wondering why you care - why not just run the query?

Comment: Thanks, this is an extremely large table, and the cardinality of the result needs to be known so resources can be procured. "just running the query" in my case would require a lot of compute time and resources for the result, even if the result was only ephemeral.

Comment: More of a side note (and obviously just based on the information provided as I don’t know your full solution) but if adding one field to an aggregate requires you to “procure resources” then you probably need to review your architecture. Billions of rows per day is large but not exceptional and nothing that a modern analytical DB shouldn’t be able to handle reasonably easily